# Objects are finite sets, arrows are matrices. How is this a category?

Tags: category-theory, reference-request

I just started to read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.211.4754&rep=rep1&type=pdf) book on category theory.

How is this example below a category?

I have difficulty imagining what this construct really is.

Could someone please illuminate me ?

I have a physics background, I am not a mathematician.

Perhaps with some very simple example or analogy that is understandable for a physicist's mind.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:

Does this example make sense at all ?

EDIT 2:

What confuses me is that for a given object $A$, $i=|A|$ is fixed, so is $j=|B|$, 
so the location of a natural number in the matrix $F$ is determined by the size of $A$ and $B$. So the arrow from $A$ to $B$ is a number in a matrix and not the matrix itself !

EDIT 3: Many thanks for the answers ! I think I get it now.

Example:

[image]

As a reminder a category is defined as:

[image]

EDIT 4:

I just bought the latest eBook version where this mistake has been corrected:

[image]

Comment: The definition is complete. Have you tried verifying the axioms?

Comment: Not the place to ask, please use MSE.

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to try to understand the example of a category with one object and a monoid as morphisms first.

Comment: The definition of the example makes no sense to me as it is written. Perhaps the author meant that $f$ is an arrow from $A$ to $B$ iff it is a matrix with $|A|$ rows and $|B|$ columns (and with entries in $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense to me either.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the answer you accepted is not correct. The arrows are indeed matrices. They are not functions! Nor are they numbers in matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what is going on:

The objects are finite sets.

For the morphisms: given two sets $A$ and $B$ you want a set $Mor(A,B)$ of elements/arrows $f: A \to B$. So here $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain of $f$. This needs to satisfy the composition law.

Here you have for two finite sets $A$ and $B$ this set of morphisms consists of all $\lvert A \rvert\times\lvert B\rvert$ matrices (with entries in $\mathbb{N}$). That is, a morphism/arrow is exactly a matrix. You compose two morphisms/arrows by multiplying the matrices. So The composition of morphisms/arrows is given by matrix multiplication so that if $f \in Mor (A,B)$ and $g\in Mor(B,C)$, then $g\circ f\in Mor(A, C)$. Is this well defined? Yes, because $Mor(A,C)$ consists exactly of $\lvert A \rvert\times\lvert C\rvert$ matrices and you get that from multiplying $\lvert A \rvert\times\lvert B\rvert$ matrices with $\lvert B \rvert\times\lvert C\rvert$ matrices.

Comment: According to the author’s definition of a category, given a arrow $f$, there must be an object $dom(f)$. Given a $m\times n$ matrix $f$, what is $dom(f)$? If there’s more than one object $A$ with $|A|=m$, $dom(f)$ isn’t well defined. Or else the arrows have to be more than just matrices, so they carry information about which specific sets are their $dom$ and $cod$. Or the author’s definition of category is wrong.

Comment: @SteveKass: Given $f\in Mor(A,B)$ the domain is $A$ and the codomain is $B$. We write $f \to B$. So indeed there is just *one* object for the domain and *one* for codomain.

Comment: The author says the arrows are matrices. If I show you one and say this is $f$, what is $dom(f)$? You can find the cardinality of $dom(f)$ from $f$ (count its rows) if $f$ is a matrix, but you can't look at the matrix and tell me what $A$ is. There's a problem with the author's example. Maybe I don't understand category theory, but if given $f$, there is *one* object $dom(f)$, isn't it a problem if it's impossible to determine what that object is, given $f$ (a matrix)? And if $\{1\}$ and $\{9\}$ are objects, aren't $id_{\{1\}}$ and $id_{\{9\}}$ different arrows? Yet they are the same matrix.

Comment: @SteveKass: I think that you have misunderstood the definition of a category. In general for any two objects $a$ and $b$ in a category you have a set $Mor(a,b)$ (sometimes also denoted $Hom(a,b)$. The elements in this set satisfy certain requirements. For an element $f\in Mor(a,b)$ we write $f: a\to b$ abstractly and in this setup the *object* $a$ is called the domain of $f$ and the *object* $b$ is called the codomain. Whenever you have a morphism, you always have a domain and a codomain. It does not make sense to take about an $f$ without an $A$ or $B$.

Comment: I am going by Definition 1.1 in the extract of this question. It says nothing about the set $Mor(a,b)$, but I'm realizing that this is crucial to the definition. How would anyone read Definition 1.1 and not be confused? Definition 1.1 fails to mention that arrows in different morphism sets aren't the same. It's like defining numbers and then telling someone they should have realized "the integer 7" and "the real number 7" are not the same. I can imagine a world where they aren't, but Definition 1.1 doesn't give a clue.

Comment: Also, since "It does not make sense to talk about an $f$ without an $A$ or $B$," would you agree that it also makes no sense to say that $f$ is a matrix? You can't give a mathematician a matrix and expect her to know what $A$ and $B$ you're talking about. (You've been helpful and careful here, but some commenters seem to insist that the arrows in this category simply are matrices. That seems problematic, because they have to be "matrices with context.")

Comment: @SteveKass: I agree! The definition that way it is written isn't great. A key point about category theory is to be precise and this definition isn't very precise.

Comment: @SteveKass: Exactly that I was thinking. It doesn't make sense to talk about $f$ without $A$ and $B$. Now, it does make sense to say that $f$ is a matrix because the (set of) morphisms can be any abstract set. Usually we like to think about the morphisms/arrows as functions, but they don't have to be. There doesn't need to be much of a relation between the morphisms and the objects.

Comment: It makes sense to say that a particular $f$ is a matrix, and for this category (call it $C$), it makes sense to say $hom(A,B)$ is a particular set of matrices. What doesn't make sense is to say that $hom(C)$ is a set of matrices, and the book's example suggested that to me.

Comment: @SteveKass: Note that $Hom(C)$ doesn't make sense. We only have $Hom$ of given two objects.

Comment: I took $Hom(C)$ from the Wikipedia article on category theory. I like your point of view better, but it's apparently not uncommon for people to talk about $Hom(C)$. Maybe they shouldn't. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#Categories.2C_objects.2C_and_morphisms_2

Comment: @SteveKass: Ok. I see. I wasn't aware that people used that notation. From what I can see $Hom(C)$ would be the total collection of all morphisms. Usually what we are interested in are the $Hom(A,B)$ for concrete objects.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is indeed worded incorrectly. I assume the author really wanted to write $F=(n_{i\,j})_{1\le i\le\lvert A\rvert,1\le j\le\lvert B\rvert}$.

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense then. I am always very confused when learning new mathematics and then find something I don't understand. Then I am not sure if it was the author's mistake or mine. Usually it's me who does not understand the new material and that is why I was asking it here if it is me who is not understanding what this really is. Or is this just a typo that is driving me crazy ?

Comment: I agree that this is confusing if you do not already know where the author is headed. I on the other hand to to reread the paragraph to see the problem, because I was already focussed on the next step. Your explanation headed by *EDIT 2* was helpful.

Comment: Oh, and I had not seen that the answer had already been given as a comment...

Comment: It was good to get a confirmation, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think the intended example is this:

The objects are finite sets and given two objects $A$ and $B$, $hom(A,B)$ is the set of all $|A| \times |B|$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{N}$ (you could replace $\mathbb{N}$ here by $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or anything for which matrix multiplication is well defined and associative). Then it is straightforward to check the axioms.

Comment: I'm still confused. Suppose $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$ are two of the objects. Then let $f$ be the $1\times1$ matrix $(1)$. The definition says that for $f$, there are objects $dom(f)$ and $cod(f)$. What are they? And the definition says that there are identity arrows on both $A$ and $B$. If the arrows are matrices, $1_A$ and $1_B$ are the same matrix, $f$. But $A=dom(1_A)\ne dom(1_B)=B$, yet if we replace both $1_A$ and $1_B$ by $f$, how can $dom(f)\ne dom(f)$?

Comment: @Steve Kass There are infinite arrows between A and B, perhaps this might resolve the contradiction you depicted.

Comment: @SteveKass: I guess you are right and technically one should "label" the arrows in $hom(A,B)$ so that (for instance) they really are triples $(A,B,F)$ where $F$ is a matrix and the composition is $(A,B,F)\circ(B,C,G)=(A,C,FG)$. Still, this is an essentially different category than the one described in user18921´s answer, and I think it is closer to the intended category in the OP´s example.

Comment: @jhegedus the problem is not that there are multiple arrows between A and B, the problem is that it is not possible to retrieve A and B uniquely from the arrow. The interpretation mentioned by Ramiro is one way to solve it, the one by Henning in another comment a different one.

Answer (score 3):

The category the author was intending to define is as follows.

1. **Objects.** Finite sets
2. **Arrows.** An arrow $f : A \rightarrow B$ is just a function $f : A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.
3. **Composition.** The composition of arrows $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow C$ is the unique function $h : A \times C \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given as follows. $$h(a,c) = \sum_{b \in B}f(a,b)g(b,c)$$
4. **Identities.** If $A$ is an object, then $\mathrm{id}_A$ is the unique function $A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given as follows.

$$\begin{align} a=a' & \;\rightarrow\; \mathrm{id}_A(a,a')=1 \\ a\neq a' & \;\rightarrow\; \mathrm{id}_A(a,a')=0 \end{align}$$

To see what this has to do with matrices, just imagine that every object of this category is not a *set*, but rather a *totally ordered* set. Then an arrow $f : A \rightarrow B$ in this category, which as you'll recall is just a function $f : A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{N},$ can be visualized as an $|A| \times |B|$ array of natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So an arrow is a function that takes as an input any product set $A$ x $B$ and gives a natural number as the output ?

Comment: @jhegedus, precisely. (Or rather, it takes as input an *element* of a product set).

Comment: Thanks, just for the record, do you also agree that the authors formulation is incorrect as Carsten pointed out ?

Comment: @jhegedus, yes there's some serious typo's going on. Doesn't mean the author is bad or that you should necessarily find another book, though; better to forgive a few typos and focus on the things that really matter, like clarity of exposition, motivation, intuition, etc.

Comment: The objects can be represented as matrices, but that representation isn’t faithful if there are distinct objects of the same cardinality. It seems wrong to say that the arrows are matrices, because you can’t take one of these arrows $f$, say of dimensions $m\times n$, and tell me what $dom(f)$ is, unless there is only one object with cardinality $m$. (Similarly in regular algebra, if we have sets and functions between them, you can’t tell me what the domain of $f(x)=x^2$ is without knowing anything else.)

Comment: @SteveKass: The objects are not matrices. The objects are finite sets.

Comment: The arrows are not functions. If you look at the example copied by the OP it expressly says that arrows are not functions. That is the whole point about the example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "arrows can be represented as matrices," not objects. The book says arrows are matrices. I agree with @user18921 that the arrows should be functions. An "array of natural numbers" (user18921's words) can represent a function between two specific ordered sets, but the arrows can't just be matrices as the book says. A function "knows" which sets it's a function between. A matrix for that function (assuming ordered sets) only "knows" the sets' sizes, not which specific sets it's a function between. So the arrows in this example have more information in them than matrices.

Comment: @SteveKass: Again, the arrows are truely and precisely matrices. They are not functions. That is the whole point of the example.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. I presumed, wrongly it seems, that the requirement that for each arrow there are given objects $dom(f)$ and $cod(f)$ meant that those objects were well-defined from $f$. But this is still very confusing to me. Is the collection of arrows a set? If it is, and it's a set of matrices, then the $1\times1$ identity matrix appears only once. Suppose both $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are objects, and consider the arrow $(1)$ ($1\times1$ matrix). What are $dom((1))$ and $cod((1))$?

Comment: @SteveKass: *Is the collection of arrows a set?* Good question. Usually this is the case. But technically it is only required to be a *class*. In this example here the collection of morphisms actually is a set. It is the set of matrices with entries in the natural numbers. Note that there are no restriction on the size of the matrices. The objects are finite sets. An arrow is a specific matrix. If you consider two sets $X$ and $Y$ both with just one element, then then the $1\times 1$ matrix $\{1\}$ is an arrow from $X$ to $Y$. Note again that this matrix is not a function. It is just a matrix.

Comment: @Thomas It is perfectly reasonable to identify an $n$ by $m$ matrix of natural numbers with a function from $n \times m$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, this is the most straightforward definition of a matrix that comes to mind.

Comment: @Kundor: A key point about category theory is to be very precise about everything. You just want to make identifications, you want to stick to the definitions as given. It is true that there are different ways to *think* about matrices, but the most commonly accepted is as certain subsets of $\mathbb{N}^m$. When one is starting out learning about category theory I think it is important to keep things precise.

Comment: @Kundor: So you might also have the category of finite sets where the morphisms are functions (like you mention). This will give you a different category, but the categories might be isomorphic/equivalent.

Comment: @Thomas: And $\mathbb{N}^m$ is defined as the set of functions $m \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean by ${\Bbb N}^m$ here? At the very least you need your "definition of an $n\times m$ matrix" to contain both $n$ and $m$. What you give would adequately describe the set of all $m$-vectors (on the natural numbers), but not matrices.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I would mean the Cartesian product of the sets $\mathbb{N}$. That is the set of ordered "pairs". That said, there is a the notion of a product in a category. Viewing it like so, there are different ways of constructing the objects.

Comment: @Kundor: Or it is defined as ordered "pairs"...

Comment: @Thomas So you mean to say $\Bbb N^m=((\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\times\Bbb N)\times\dots\times\Bbb N$, where there are $m$ copies of $\Bbb N$ in the product, and $\times$ is the cartesian product of sets? But that still doesn't make sense insofar as the number $n$ is still not present in the definition...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "*the number n is still not present in the definition*". Are you talking about the definition of the category in the OP's question?

Comment: @Thomas I mean, finish the sentence: "An $m\times n$ matrix is defined as ___". If the ___ does not contain the variable $n$, then why is it in the definiendum? (For the record, I agree with Kundor's characterization: an $m\times n$ matrix is an element of $\Bbb N^{m\times n}$, that is, a function from $m\times n$ to $\Bbb N$.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Ok. So an $m\times n$ martrix $A$ wiht entries in $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as any subset of $\mathbb{N}^{nm}$. You can then define the multiplication of an $m\times n$ with an $n\times p$ the usual way.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Also, I know that there are different constructions of the natural numbers. I would use the standard set theoretic construction.

Comment: @Thomas Are you sure you mean subset (not element)? Letting $n=m=1$, you would consider $\{1,2,4,8,\dots\}$ a $1\times 1$ matrix?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: You are right. I, of course, meant element. This discussion is getting too long :)

Comment: @Thomas Then it seems you and I (and Kundor) are in agreement, since $A^B$ is the space of functions from $B$ to $A$, so a matrix is indeed a function $f:(m\times n)\to\Bbb N$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Or, $\mathbb{N}^m$ is defined as $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ where the elements are tuples $(a_1, \dots, a_m)$. My point is still that it is better to call the arrows/morphisms matrices and not functions.

Comment: @Thomas: The problem with saying that it's "just" matrices is that doing so requires the objects to be not just finite sets, but finite sets _with a distinguished enumeration of their elements_ that specifies which rows/columns of the matrix correspond to which elements of the set. Then the whole thing collapses into the category of dimensions (as objects) and matrices (as morphisms) with some of the objects uselessly duplicated. It's more faithful to the original idea to keep the ordering of each finite set abstract, which is what the $\mathbb N^{A\times B}$ construction achieves.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I am not sure that I follow your line of thought. I don't there is a problem with saying that the objects are finite sets and that the morphisms are (certain) matrices. Granted we can discuss how to best define matrices, but when the OP's example states them as matrices, why would you want to say that they are actually not matrices? I makes more sense to keep the language of the example. I believe that this is key in the idea of categpory theory - in particular when you first start learning about it (as it seems that the OP is doing).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: It is like saying that two groups are the same if they are isomorphic. This is "fine" when you are familiar with the definition of a group, but initially when you are starting out it makes more sense to distinguish between isomorphic and equal.

Comment: @HenningMakholm and others: Maybe we can continue this discussion here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13781/discussion-about-categories-matrices-functions

Comment: (That chatroom is empty). @Thomas: The problem is that your definition completely ignores the _elements_ of the finite sets that are the objects of the category. That makes the construction completely unmotivated -- we could just as well say that the objects are natural numbers, and the morphism would work equally well for that. If there is to be any point to the category it must be that the sets that are the objects help define how the morphisms fit together when they compose.

Comment: An alternative way to say this is that a morphism $A\to B$ is a linear map between the space of formal linear combinations of $A$ and the space of formal linear combinations of $B$. Such a map can be _represented_ as a matrix, but doing so comes at the cost of having to select a particular ordering on the elements of $A$ and $B$ -- which is an extraneous detail that it's the job of category theory to _abstract away_ from.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The chat room seems to be working, no? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13781/discussion-about-categories-matrices-functions I have responded to you there.